# SwiftUI iBeacon detection proximity and display different Storyboard or view

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ibeacon

Is it possible to display different storyboards based on near, far or immediate of the iBeacon proximity?

here is the code I am using.

```
    func updateDistance(_ distance: CLProximity) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8) {
            switch distance {
            case .unknown:
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                self.proximityLabel.text = "unknown"

            case .far:
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
                  self.proximityLabel.text = "far"

            case .near:
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
                 self.proximityLabel.text = "near"

            case .immediate:
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                 self.proximityLabel.text = "immediate"
            default:
                fatalError()
            }
        }
    }
```

Regards,

Comment: I don't see anything related to SwiftUI here. Would you add some code?

Comment: Asperi, I have added the code I am using to my post